# Local windows - Server Ubuntu, git push live no putty

Tags: django, git

I've a django app, i'd like to set-up with git remote with `git push live` command pushing onto AWS EC2
all methods mentioned use putty which isn't able to config it

I've set up a bare repository with edits(https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa) done to using this as a reference

all works fine until I need to hit

```
$ git remote add production demo@yourserver.com:project.git
```

this line, as ssh was through putty, I faced issues here

Answer (score 0):

Git post hook windows 10 - Linux system

After setting up the bare repository and configuring it for posthooks

**`Everything from here would be done in the local machine`**

Check-in Windows `Manage Optional features`

Install and activate - OpenSSH Client & OpenSSH Server

Create a new config file in .ssh directory which would be located in {user}/.ssh

```
Host foobar
  HostName {HostName of EC2 instance}
  Port 22
  User {user}
  IdentityFile {.pem file location}
```

after this go to the project directory and

```
git remote add live foobar:{barerepositoryname}.git
```

and done!

try - `git push live` now